# using Count(*) to count number of employees assigned to company

Tags: mysql, sql

My code works out so that Companys have stores, stores have departments and departments have employees and employees have subtypes eg. full time.

i need to count the amount of full time employees for a company and display the companies address and name along with the AMOUNT of employees.

My current code looks like this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.COMPANY_NAME, C.COMPANY_ADDRESS
FROM COMPANY C, FTEMPLOYEE FT, EMPLOYEES E, STORE S, DEPARTMENTS D
Where(
Count(*) From FTEMPLOYEE
);
```

Comment: Could you please share your tables' structure?

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your database design looks like. An example where your FTEmployee table has direct reference (i.e. foreign key) to Company table, your query would look like:

```
select count(e.id), c.name, c.address 
from ftemployee e 
inner join company c
on c.id = e.company_id  
group by c.name
```